# set HtmlWebViewSource html property

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

```
WebView webView = new WebView();
            var source = new HtmlWebViewSource();
            source.Html = "<html><body><h1>Header</h1></body></html>";
            webView.Source = source;
            layout.Children.Add(webView);

            Label label = new Label { Text = "deneme" };
            layout.Children.Add(label);
```

I try use WebView and prepared above codes.When debuging label ( deneme ) is appeared , but webview text (header) not appeared.What should i do?

Comment: Try setting the height of the webview and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I figure out the problem.The problem was webview in stacklayout.I put the webview in grid in stacklayout at xaml document.No webview is visible.

```
<StackLayout x:Name="layout">
  <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="*" />
      <RowDefinition Height="750" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Label Text="Deneme" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"/>
    <WebView Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="webView" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
  </Grid>
</StackLayout>
```